# No attribute "execute" error on connecting to PostgreSQL

Tags: pandas, postgresql, python-3.11, postgresql-15

I have my postgres installed on PC1 and I am connecting to the database using PC2. I have modified the settings so that postgres on PC1 is accessible to local network.

On PC2 I am doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd, pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
z1 = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:***@192.168.40.154:5432/myDB')
z2 = pd.read_sql(fr"""select * from public."myTable" """, z1)
```

I get the error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1405, in execute
    return self.connectable.execution_options().execute(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'OptionEngine' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

While running the same code on PC1 I get no error.

I just noticed that it happens only when reading from the db. If I do `to_sql` it works. Seems there is missing on the PC2 as instead of trying `192.168.40.154:5432` if I use `localhost:5432` I get the same error.

Edit:
Following modification worked but not sure why. Can someone please educate me what could be the reason for this.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text
connection = connection = z1.connect()
stmt = text("SELECT * FROM public.myTable")
z2 = pd.read_sql(stmt, connection)
```

Edit2:

```
PC1:
pd.__version__
'1.5.2'
import sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy.__version__
'1.4.46'


PC2:
pd.__version__
'1.5.3'
import sqlalchemy
sqlalchemy.__version__
'2.0.0'
```

Does it mean that if I update the packages on PC1 everything is going to break?

Comment: What versions of SQLAlchemy and Pandas? Add information as update to question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into the same problem just today and basically it's the SQLalchemy version, if you look at the documentation [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/intro.html#installation) the SQLalchemy version 2.0.0 was released a few days ago so pandas is not updated, for now I think the solution is sticking with the 1.4.x version.

Comment: Did you open an issue already ?

Answer (score 1):

The `sqlalchemy.sql.text()` part is not the issue. The addition of `connection()` to the `connect_engine()` instruction seems to have done the trick.

Comment: I tried both connection and text and they both need to be present for the code to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should also use a context manager in addition to a SQLAlchemy SQL clause using `text`, e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd, pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:***@192.168.40.154:5432/myDB')

with engine.begin() as connection: 
    res = pd.read_sql(
        sql=text(fr'SELECT * FROM public."myTable"'),
        con=connection,
    )
```

As explained here https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html :

> conSQLAlchemy connectable, str, or sqlite3 connection
>
> Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB supported by that library. If a DBAPI2 object, only sqlite3 is supported. The user is
> responsible for engine disposal and connection closure for the
> SQLAlchemy connectable; str connections are closed automatically. See
> [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html).

--> especially this point: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/connections.html#connect-and-begin-once-from-the-engine